# Adding confidence intervals to logarithmic regression

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval

I am trying to add confidence intervals to a logarithmic regression curve in R. I assume there is a mathematical reason that I'm so far unable to do this, so any help would be appreciated.

Here's the data:

```
Treatment<-c(15,12,6,3,15,12,6,9,9,15,6,9,3,3,12)
CSA<-c(70.32255036, 141.7157414,    185.6793193,    382.1145078,    51.68417543,    
       99.38527948, 164.1865075,    160.8565834,    43.85808722,    46.99992099,
       75.46593836, 116.4039474,    250.3521394,    290.2665555,    122.2660148)
data<-data.frame(Treatment, CSA)
```

And here's the code to generate the plot

```
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
par(mar=c(2.5,2.5,1,1))

plot(data$Treatment,data$CSA,ylim=c(0,400),xlim=c(3,15),pch=21,
     xaxt="n",yaxt="n",cex=0.6,xlab=NA,ylab=NA,bty="l")

axis(side=1,tck=-0.02,at=seq(3,15,3),cex.axis=0.6,
     mgp=c(0,0.3,0))
axis(side=2,tck=-0.02,at=seq(0,400,100),cex.axis=0.6,
     las=2,mgp=c(0,.5,0))

ylab<-expression("Total cross-sectional area (cm"^{2}~")")
xlab<-c("Treatment")

mtext(xlab,side=1,line=1.5,cex=0.7)
mtext(ylab,side=2,line=1.5,cex=0.7)

model <- nls(CSA ~ a*log(Treatment)+b,start = 
               list(a = -141,b = 437),data=data)    

xv<-seq(min(data$Treatment),max(data$Treatment),0.5)
yv<-predict(model,list(Treatment=xv))
lines(xv,yv,col="grey23",lwd=1.5)
```

[image: LOGARITHMIC REGRESSION PLOT]

If I fit a second order polynomial model to the plot using;

```
mod2<-lm(CSA~poly(Treatment,2),data=data)
xv<-seq(min(data$Treatment),max(data$Treatment),0.5)
yv<-predict(mod2,list(Treatment=xv))
lines(xv,yv,col="grey23",lwd=1.5)
```

I can add in confidence intervals using;

```
newx <- seq(min(data$Treatment), max(data$Treatment), length.out=1000)
preds <- predict(mod2, newdata = data.frame(Treatment=newx), 
                 interval = 'confidence')
lines(newx, preds[ ,3], lty = 'dashed', col = "grey36",lwd=1)
lines(newx, preds[ ,2], lty = 'dashed', col = 'grey36',lwd=1)
```

[image: POLYNOMIAL REGRESSION MODEL]

But that doesn't work for the logarithmic curve. Is there a way I can do this in base R?

Thanks in advance

Comment: not sure why you're using `nls` -- that model is linear in the parameters of interest (`a` and `b`)

Comment: can you add the output of the plot you're getting at the moment? also please include `dput(data)` to make it easier for us to reproduce

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - Confidence bands for exponential model (nls) in basic graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459480/r-confidence-bands-for-exponential-model-nls-in-basic-graphics)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine using `lm` to fit a linear model to the log-transformed data

```
mod3 <- lm(CSA ~ log(Treatment),data=data)    
yv<-predict(mod3,list(Treatment=xv))
lines(xv,yv,col="grey23",lwd=1.5)
preds <- predict(mod3, newdata = data.frame(Treatment=newx), 
                 interval = 'confidence')
lines(newx, preds[ ,3], lty = 'dashed', col = "grey36",lwd=1)
lines(newx, preds[ ,2], lty = 'dashed', col = 'grey36',lwd=1)
```

[image]